# How do I specify the Java VM which should be used to build the release during mvn unleash:perform?

Tags: maven-3, maven-unleash-plugin

I get build errors when using `mvn unleash:perform` because it tries to use the default Java VM to build the release instead of the one pointed to with `JAVA_HOME` or the one which was used to start the maven-unleash-plugin.

With `-Dunleash.releaseArgs="--debug=true" -X`, I can see that the outer Maven uses Java 11 and the inner uses 8.

I tried to fix this with:

```
mvn unleash:perform -Dunleash.releaseEnvironment="JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" -X |& tee mvn.log
```

but that leads to an NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itemis.maven.plugins.unleash.steps.actions.BuildProject.setupInvocationRequest (BuildProject.java:123)
    at com.itemis.maven.plugins.unleash.steps.actions.BuildProject.execute (BuildProject.java:73)
```

Is changing the default VM in Windows my only option?

Comment: Is there reason why using an unmaintainend plugin ?

Comment: For my use cases (stable CI builds) it's  better than any alternatives. `mvn deploy` for example has many unresolved bugs like `deployAtEnd` not working reliably.

Comment: First have [you tried the most recent version](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/)? And can you offer and example project which shows the problem? Also many unresolved bugs? Hm.. [21](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+JIRA+issues+overview) ? Ok...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit was in `.mavenrc` (Linux) or `%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd` (Windows, also check `%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.bat`). There, `JAVA_HOME` was hardcoded to some specific path.

The fix is to a) only set `JAVA_HOME` when it has no value and b) to display a warning (with path) when the variable is set. That way, people can't get confused by some silent behavior.

Solution in `.mavenrc`:

```
if [[ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]]; then
    export JAVA_HOME=...
    echo "~/.mavenrc: Setting JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
fi
```

For `%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd`, use:

```
if "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    set JAVA_HOME=...
    echo %USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd: Setting JAVA_HOME to %JAVA_HOME%
)
```